# how to get local timezone datetime for date comparison in django

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I am trying to fire a reminder based on a users timezone.  The users timezone is 'America/New_York'

I attempt to get the users time with the following:

```
now = datetime.now()
now_plus_10 = test_customer.time_zone.localize(now + timedelta(minutes = 10))
now_minus_10 = test_customer.time_zone.localize(now + timedelta(minutes = -10))
```

The reminder time is at 13:00.  It is gathered from the customer object like this:

```
 reminder = customer.reminder #set to 13:00
```

I then want to send a reminder if within 10 minutes + or - of the reminder.

I do the comparison like:

```
if reminder > now_minus_10 and gb_real_time < now_plus_10: 
    reminder_email.send()
else:
    print 'ceiling '+str(now_plus_10)
    print 'not in window don t send'
    print 'floor '+str(now_minus_10)
```

This prints:

```
ceiling 2014-09-03 10:10:54.547901-04:00  
not in window don t send
floor 2014-09-03 09:50:54.547901-04:00
```

I am in the timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles' in which it is 10:00am

Why is it that even though I localized now_plus_10 and now_minus_10 dates, but they do not convert to New_York time which would make them 13:00 like the reminder and in turn fire the reminder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood what `localize()` does. (I assume you're talking about the pytz `localize()`, in which case you can see the documentation [here](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).)

It doesn't *convert* times, it takes a naive (timezone-unaware) datetime and makes it aware (*assigns* it a timezone). Here's what's going on in your example:

```
now = datetime.now()  # 10:00am local time (no timezone)
later = now + timedelta(minutes=10)  # 10:10am (no timezone)
now_plus_10 = ny_timezone.localize(later)  # 10:10am (NY timezone)
```

If you really want to convert between timezones directly, using `pytz`, you can do something like this:

```
now = la_timzeone.localize(datetime.now())  # 10:00am local time (LA timezone)
later = now + timedelta(minutes=10)  # 10:10am (LA timezone)
later_safe = la_timezone.normalize(later)  # because of DST and such
later_ny = later_safe.astimezone(ny_timezone)  # 13:10 (NY timezone)
later_ny_safe = ny_timezone.normalize(later_ny)  # again
```

Now, that's complicated! Which is why both `pytz` and Django discourage you from manually localizing and converting time zones. You'll have to review the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/), but basically the Django approach is this:

- All internal datetimes are timezone-aware and use UTC.
- Use [`django.utils.timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) to get the current time in UTC.
- User-entered datetimes (for example, if your user enters his or her reminder time in a form) are automatically made aware. To do this you have to know the user's timezone and then call [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate). You can also do it manually with [`localtime()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime).
- Do all of your comparisons and arithmetic with these UTC datetimes.

I definitely recommend doing things the Django way.

Comment: How do I localize the reminder which is at 13:00 relative to the user's timezone?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Atma:: If you mean manually, with pytz, `user_tz.localize(reminder)` would make it timezone-aware and then you could compare it with your timezone-aware current time. If using Django's timezone support, you would call `activate(user_tz)` and then the reminder time you get back from the form or the database would be timezone-aware and accurate.